# Arduino Keypad breaking whole code (alarm clock)

Tags: arduino, i2c

I'm currently programming an alarm clock with a 4x4 keypad, i2c 20x4 Lcd, DS3231 and buzzer.
Everything works, but I have problems with implementing the menu to change alarm times and other settings.

Sadly I'm under time pressure so this is very important to me. Any help is acknowledged.

The menu shows up and when I press a key it returns to the normal screen showing the clock. I tried debugging with Serial and it breaks off here (a schematic ) :

```
void menu(int menupos) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("1. Alarme einstellen");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("2. Sprache einst.");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("3. Beleuchtung einst");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("9. Zurueck");
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  while (keypressm == NO_KEY) {
    keypressm = Tastenfeld2.getKey();

   // A Serial Print here still works but after a key is pressed it returns to the clock.

}
  if (keypressm == "1") {
    menuSetAlarm();
  } else if (keypressm == "2") {
    menuSetLanguage();
  } else if (keypressm == "3") {
    menuOtherSettings();
  } else if (keypressm == "9") {
    lcd.clear();
    loop();
  }
  lcd.clear();
}
```

Here's the whole code (without EEPROM stuff)

```
#include <TimedAction.h>
#include <Wire.h>                                                                                         // I2C Adress
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>                                                                            // Library for I2C LCD Displays
#include <Keypad.h>                                                                                       // Keypad Libary
#include "RTClib.h"                                                                                       // Library for DS3231 RTC

//Hier wird die größe des Keypads definiert
const byte COLS = 4; //4 Spalten
const byte ROWS = 4; //4 Zeilen

//Die Ziffern und Zeichen des Keypads werden eingegeben:
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '4', '7', '*'},
  {'2', '5', '8', '0'},
  {'3', '6', '9', '#'},
  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
};

RTC_DS3231 rtc;                                                                                           // declare RTC
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);                                            // declare LCD module (I2C adress, RS, E, D4, D5, D6, D7, backlightpin, polarity)
DateTime now;

byte colPins[COLS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //Definition der Pins für die 4 Spalten
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //Definition der Pins für die 4 Zeilen
char key; //Taste ist die Variable für die jeweils gedrückte Taste.
char keypressx; //Taste um alarm abzubrechen
char keypressm; //menukeyw
Keypad Tastenfeld = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); //Das Keypad kann absofort mit "Tastenfeld" angesprochen werden
Keypad Tastenfeld2 = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); //Das Keypad kann absofort mit "Tastenfeld2" angesprochen werden


int menupos = -1;

boolean currentStateBacklight = true;
boolean scheduledBacklight = false;

int bs_ontime;
int bs_offtime;

const int alarm_pin = 10;

boolean endedAlarm = false;
int endedAlarmTime;

boolean alarm1_active = false;
boolean alarm2_active = false;

String alarm1_hour;
String alarm1_minute;
String alarm1_second;
String alarm1Days[] = {};

String alarm2_hour;
String alarm2_minute;
String alarm2_second;
String alarm2Days[] = {};

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(250000);
  delay(3000);                                                                                            // wait for console opening

  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }

  if (rtc.lostPower()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, lets set the time!");

    // Comment out below lines once you set the date & time.
    // Following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  }


  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.begin(20, 4);                                                                                       // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows
  Wire.begin();
}
void loop() {
  key = NO_KEY;
  keypressx = NO_KEY;
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  while (key == NO_KEY) {
    key = Tastenfeld.getKey();
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    if (endedAlarm) {
      if ((millis() - endedAlarmTime) > 60000) {
        endedAlarm = false;
        endedAlarmTime = 0;
      }
    }
    String nowhour = correctedValue(now.hour());
    String nowmin = correctedValue(now.minute());
    String nowsec = correctedValue(now.second());
    String nowday = daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()];
    if (alarm1_active && nowhour == alarm1_hour && nowmin == alarm1_minute && !endedAlarm && arrayIncludeElement(alarm1Days, nowday)) { // && correctedValue(now.second()) == alarm1_second) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(1, 10);
      lcd.print("Get up !!!"); //Message to show when the alarm is ringing
      int z = 0;
      int x = 1000;
      int y = 430;
      while (keypressx == NO_KEY) {
        tone(alarm_pin, 2870);
        keypressx = Tastenfeld.getKey();
        delay(y);
        noTone(alarm_pin);
        keypressx = Tastenfeld.getKey();
        delay(x);
        x = x * 0.95999;
        y = y * 0.97999;
        keypressx = Tastenfeld.getKey();
      }
      endedAlarm = true;
      endedAlarmTime = millis();
      lcd.clear();
    }
    if (alarm2_active && nowhour == alarm2_hour && nowmin == alarm2_minute && !endedAlarm && arrayIncludeElement(alarm2Days, nowday)) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(1, 10);
      lcd.print("Get up !!!"); //Message to show when the alarm is ringing
      int z = 0;
      int x = 1000;
      int y = 430;
      while (keypressx == NO_KEY) {
        tone(alarm_pin, 2870);
        keypressx = Tastenfeld.getKey();
        delay(y);
        noTone(alarm_pin);
        keypressx = Tastenfeld.getKey();
        delay(x);
        x = x * 0.95999;
        y = y * 0.97999;
        keypressx = Tastenfeld.getKey();
      }
      endedAlarm = true;
      endedAlarmTime = millis();
      lcd.clear();
    }
    keypressx = NO_KEY;
    noTone(alarm_pin);
    now = rtc.now();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);                                                                                    //Text soll beim ersten Zeichen in der ersten Reihe beginnen..
    lcd.print("");                                                                      //In der ersten Zeile soll der Text „Test Zeile 1“ angezeigt werden
    lcd.setCursor(18, 0);
    if (alarm1_active == true) {
      lcd.print("A1");
    }
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);                                                                                    //Genauso geht es bei den weiteren drei Zeilen weiter
    lcd.print(correctedValue(now.hour()) + ":" + correctedValue(now.minute()) + ":" + correctedValue(now.second()));
    lcd.setCursor(18, 1);
    if (alarm2_active == true) {
      lcd.print("A2");
    }
    lcd.setCursor(7, 2);
    lcd.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
    lcd.setCursor(5, 3);
    lcd.print(correctedValue(now.day()) + "." + correctedValue(now.month()) + "." + String(now.year()));
    delay(100);
  }
  Serial.println(key);
  if (key == '1') {
    if (alarm1_active) {
      alarm1_active = false;
      lcd.clear();
    } else {
      alarm1_active = true;
    }
  }
  if (key == '2') {
    if (alarm2_active) {
      alarm2_active = false;
      lcd.clear();
    } else {
      alarm2_active = true;
    }
  }
  if (key == '*') {
    menu(0);
  }
}

boolean arrayIncludeElement(String array[], String element) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (array[i] == element) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

String correctedValue(char x) {
  int y;
  String z;
  y = int(x);
  if (y < 10) {
    z = String(y);
    z = "0" + z;
    return z;
  } else {
    return String(y);
  }
}

void menu(int menupos) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("1. Alarme einstellen");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("2. Sprache einst.");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("3. Beleuchtung einst");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("9. Zurueck");
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  while (keypressm == NO_KEY) {
    keypressm = Tastenfeld2.getKey();
    key = "*";
  }
  if (keypressm == "1") {
    //menupos = 1;
    menuSetAlarm();
    //menupos = 0;
  } else if (keypressm == "2") {
    //menupos = 2;
    menuSetLanguage();
    //menupos = 0;
  } else if (keypressm == "3") {
    //menupos = 3;
    menuOtherSettings();
    //menupos = 0;
  } else if (keypressm == "9") {
    lcd.clear();
    loop();
    //menupos = -1;
  }
  lcd.clear();
}

void menuSetAlarm() {
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("1. Alarm 1");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("2. Alarm 2");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("9. Zur");
  lcd.print(" #ALT228# ");
  lcd.print("ck");
  keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
  if (keypressm == "1") {

  } else if (keypressm == "2") {

  } else if (keypressm == "9") {
    lcd.clear();
    menu(0);
  }
  menu(1);
  lcd.clear();
}

void menuSetLanguage() {
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("1. Deutsch");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("2. English");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("9. Zur");
  lcd.print(" #ALT228# ");
  lcd.print("ck");
  keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
  if (keypressm == "1") {
    changeLanguage("en");
  } else if (keypressm == "2") {
    changeLanguage("de");
  } else if (keypressm == "9") {
    lcd.clear();
    menu(0);
  }
  lcd.clear();
  menu(2);
}

void menuOtherSettings() {
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("1. Permanent " + !currentStateBacklight);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("2. Geplant");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("9. Zur");
  lcd.print(" #ALT228# ");
  lcd.print("ck");
  keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
  if (keypressm == "1") {
    currentStateBacklight = !currentStateBacklight;
    if (currentStateBacklight) {
      lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
    } else {
      lcd.setBacklight(LOW);
    }
  } else if (keypressm == "2") {
    scheduledBacklight = true;
    int x;
    int y;
    // set on hour
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Einschaltzeit: (Stunde)");
    lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
    lcd.print("XX");
    keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
    if (keypressm == "#" || keypressm == "*") {
      menu(3);
    }
    if (keypressm != "#" && keypressm != "*") {
      if (keypressm == "0" || keypressm == "1" || keypressm == "2") {
        if (keypressm = "0") {
          y = 0;
        } else if (keypressm = "1") {
          y = 1;
        } else if (keypressm = "2") {
          y = 2;
        }
        x = y;
      }
      menu(3);
    }
    // 2nd digit
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Einschaltzeit: (Stunde)");
    lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
    lcd.print(x + "X");
    keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
    if (keypressm == "#" || keypressm == "*") {
      menu(3);
    }
    if (x == 2) {
      if (keypressm == "0" || keypressm == "1" || keypressm == "2" || keypressm == "3" ) {
        if (keypressm = "1") {
          y = 1;
        } else if (keypressm = "2") {
          y = 2;
        } else if (keypressm = "3") {
          y = 3;
        }
        x = (x * 10) + y;
        bs_ontime = x;
      } else if (keypressm == "4") {
        bs_ontime = 0;
      }
    }
    if (x == 1) {
      if (keypressm = "1") {
        y = 1;
      } else if (keypressm = "2") {
        y = 2;
      } else if (keypressm = "3") {
        y = 3;
      } else if (keypressm = "4") {
        y = 4;
      } else if (keypressm = "5") {
        y = 5;
      } else if (keypressm = "6") {
        y = 6;
      } else if (keypressm = "7") {
        y = 7;
      } else if (keypressm = "8") {
        y = 8;
      } else if (keypressm = "9") {
        y = 9;
      } else if (keypressm = "0") {
        y = 0;
      }
      x = (x * 10) + y;
      bs_ontime = x;
    }
    if (x == 0) {
      if (keypressm = "1") {
        y = 1;
      } else if (keypressm = "2") {
        y = 2;
      } else if (keypressm = "3") {
        y = 3;
      } else if (keypressm = "4") {
        y = 4;
      } else if (keypressm = "5") {
        y = 5;
      } else if (keypressm = "6") {
        y = 6;
      } else if (keypressm = "7") {
        y = 7;
      } else if (keypressm = "8") {
        y = 8;
      } else if (keypressm = "9") {
        y = 9;
      } else if (keypressm = "0") {
        y = 0;
      }
      x = (x * 10) + y;
      bs_ontime = x;
    }

    // set on hour
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Einschaltzeit: (Stunde)");
    lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
    lcd.print("XX");
    keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
    if (keypressm == "#" || keypressm == "*") {
      menu(3);
    }
    if (keypressm != "#" && keypressm != "*") {
      if (keypressm == "0" || keypressm == "1" || keypressm == "2") {
        if (keypressm = "0") {
          y = 0;
        } else if (keypressm = "1") {
          y = 1;
        } else if (keypressm = "2") {
          y = 2;
        }
        x = y;
      }
      menu(3);
    }
    // 2nd digit
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Einschaltzeit: (Stunde)");
    lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
    lcd.print(x + "X");
    keypressm = Tastenfeld.waitForKey();
    if (keypressm == "#" || keypressm == "*") {
      menu(3);
    }
    if (x == 2) {
      if (keypressm == "0" || keypressm == "1" || keypressm == "2" || keypressm == "3" ) {
        if (keypressm = "1") {
          y = 1;
        } else if (keypressm = "2") {
          y = 2;
        } else if (keypressm = "3") {
          y = 3;
        }
        x = (x * 10) + y;
        bs_offtime = x;
      } else if (keypressm == "4") {
        bs_offtime = 0;
      }
    }
    if (x == 1) {
      if (keypressm = "1") {
        y = 1;
      } else if (keypressm = "2") {
        y = 2;
      } else if (keypressm = "3") {
        y = 3;
      } else if (keypressm = "4") {
        y = 4;
      } else if (keypressm = "5") {
        y = 5;
      } else if (keypressm = "6") {
        y = 6;
      } else if (keypressm = "7") {
        y = 7;
      } else if (keypressm = "8") {
        y = 8;
      } else if (keypressm = "9") {
        y = 9;
      } else if (keypressm = "0") {
        y = 0;
      }
      x = (x * 10) + y;
      bs_offtime = x;
    }
    if (x == 0) {
      if (keypressm = "1") {
        y = 1;
      } else if (keypressm = "2") {
        y = 2;
      } else if (keypressm = "3") {
        y = 3;
      } else if (keypressm = "4") {
        y = 4;
      } else if (keypressm = "5") {
        y = 5;
      } else if (keypressm = "6") {
        y = 6;
      } else if (keypressm = "7") {
        y = 7;
      } else if (keypressm = "8") {
        y = 8;
      } else if (keypressm = "9") {
        y = 9;
      } else if (keypressm = "0") {
        y = 0;
      }
      x = (x * 10) + y;
      bs_offtime = x;
      lcd.clear();
    }

  } else if (keypressm == "9") {
    lcd.clear();
    menu(0);
  }
  lcd.clear();
  menupos = 1;
}
```

Comment: What does `Tastenfeld.getKey()` return? A `char` or a `char *` or a `String`?

Comment: Never explicitly call `loop()` in an Arduino program.

Comment: `getKey()` returns a `char`. You're then comparing it to a `const char*` (`"1"`, `"2"`, etc.) Change your double quotes to single quotes. This comparison can be done, but is unsafe, and I'm surprised the code is compiling at all. `"1"` is actually a pointer to a spot in memory where the array `{'1', '\0'}` lives, which has a numeric address. Comparing the result of `getKey()` which is a `char` to this can be done with integer comparisons. But it will likely always be false.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is `loop();`. Test the `return;` method. Example:

```
void menu(int menupos) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("1. Alarme einstellen");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("2. Sprache einst.");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("3. Beleuchtung einst");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("9. Zurueck");
  keypressm = NO_KEY;
  while (keypressm == NO_KEY) {
    keypressm = Tastenfeld2.getKey();

   // A Serial Print here still works but after a key is pressed it returns to the clock.

}
  if (keypressm == "1") {
    menuSetAlarm();
  } else if (keypressm == "2") {
    menuSetLanguage();
  } else if (keypressm == "3") {
    menuOtherSettings();
  } else if (keypressm == "9") {
    lcd.clear();
    return; // !!
  }
  lcd.clear();
}
```

Good luck!